# Printing selected notes in OneNote 2010

Tags: microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2010

I want to print a selection of some (not all) notes from the same notebook. From what I can see, default printing options in OneNote only prints the selected page or the entire notebook. Is there a way to print only the notes I've highlighted?

Answer (score 0):

Just select all of the pages you want by holding down the ctrl button and selecting the pages then print.

Comment: This approach seemed to want to print the whole notebook for me, though.

Comment: Just make sure that the "Page Range" in the Print dialogue is set to "Selection" rather than "All". I've just tested it in ON2010, couldn't do that last night.

Answer (score 0):

To print a selection from OneNote:

Don't use the Print menu on OneNote; Use the Print option on your Google Chrome browser.

Click on the three dots in the top right corner of your browser. Choose Print.

When the print dialogue box opens, click on "More Settings."

Then check the box labeled "Selection Only."

This will print only the part of the note you selected.

Comment: I don't understand. My note isn't in my browser.